# Which pins on a GPIO TFT can I not use?

Tags: gpio, retropie

I got this [TFT](http://a.co/061EcI7) a Waveshare clone.

I am using the fbcp workaround by tasanakorn to make it display Retropie. It takes up a lot of the GPIO pins on the Raspberry Pi so I want to know which pins on the TFT can I disconnect and use for buttons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: this assumes you have a completely waveshare 3.5 inch compatible screen.
Per this product [page](http://www.waveshare.com/3.5inch-rpi-lcd-a.htm)

Pins 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12, 13, 15, 16 are not connected and hence can be used for buttons etc.

The full list of pins and their functions can be found on the waveshare product page linked above.